# How to fix java.lang.NullPointerException when call JpaRepository from another class?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm a new Java developer. When run a Spring Project with two case :
- Create another main, and call JpaRepository Method.
- From controller.impl, i call a method of a class with using a JpaRepository Method.

I got error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at solution.Testclass.getvalue(Testclass.java:20)
    at mydemo.controller.testmain.main(testmain.java:11)
```

I tried to add many notations but it does not work.

Here's my code.

Main:

```
package mydemo.controller;


import solution.Testclass;

public class testmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Testclass testclass = new Testclass();
        testclass.getvalue();
    }

}
```

Testclass.java:

```
package solution;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import mydemo.entity.HistoryUpload;
import mydemo.repository.HistoryUploadRepository;

public class Testclass {

    @Autowired HistoryUploadRepository historyUploadRepository;

    List<HistoryUpload> listHistoryUploadNullFlag;


    public List<HistoryUpload> getvalue(){

        try {

            this.listHistoryUploadNullFlag = historyUploadRepository.findAll();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.listHistoryUploadNullFlag;
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
package mydemo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import mydemo.entity.HistoryUpload;

public interface HistoryUploadRepository extends JpaRepository<HistoryUpload, Integer>{

//  List<HistoryUpload> findByStatus(String p_status);

//  @Query(value = "SELECT o.* FROM history_upload o where o.status = ?1 AND o.flag_synchronize is null",nativeQuery = true)
//  List<HistoryUpload> findByStatusAndNullFlagSynchronize(String p_status);

}
```

And my Entity

```
package mydemo.entity;

import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;


@Entity
@Table(name="history_upload")
@Data
public class HistoryUpload {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer logFileId;
    private Integer flagSynchronize;
    private Integer instance_id;
    private String instanceName;
    private Date uploadTime;
    private String status;
}
```

Please help me!
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to not be running your application as a spring boot application, which will not allow for bean creation on your repository, resulting in a null pointer exeption when you attempt to call the repository method `getAll()`

This can be added in your main class like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = *your base package, eg com.test.application*) // this is not essential but required if you use a non standard directory structure
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(TestMain.class, args);
// you will now need to access your test class through a spring bean - see below for an example using a controller endpoint:
    }

}

// in TestController
@RestController
class TestController {

    private final Testclass testClass;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(TestClass testClass) {
        this.testCLass = testClass
    }


    // now a simple endpoint to get the data, call this in postman to see the result

     @GetMapping(value = "/")
     public ResponseEntity<List<HistoryUpload>> getHsitoryList() {
         return new ResponseEntity.ok().body(TestClass.getvalue());
     }

}
```

Also avoid catching generic exceptions in your try catch block, this is generally bad practice according to the java cert standard, especially when you catch NullPointerExceptions(these chould never be caught, read more [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR08-J.+Do+not+catch+NullPointerException+or+any+of+its+ancestors))

Also in future look into logging, calling e.print stack trace can be expensive for performance, plus loggers offer more configuration, read [here](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/java-logging-basics/)

I would suggest looking into using a dedicated exception handler class, you can read about those [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-exceptionhandler-annotation/)

### Note:

Spring can be finicky when it comes to directory structure, make sure that all beans(controllers, repository, services etc) are in directories **below** the main application:

```
com
   your
       app
          Main.java
          controller / your controllers
          repositories / your repos
 ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jack Branch. I fixed my code as the way you tell me and it works. Thanks again. I wish you a happy day!